# Change pixel color in for-loop PIL Image

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I'm writing an application that writes "binary" into pixels ("1" for white, "0" for black, " " for light-gray).

This is an enlargement of what a picture like that looks like:

[image: enlarged version of smage]

I made this picture with a photoshopping app just to test, but how to actually make your application write pixels (to a .png file) in a `for`-loop?

This is the code I have written down already.

```
from PIL import Image

def makePicture(string, file):
    img = Image.new("RGB", (round(len(string)), round(len(string))), 0xffffff)
    pixel = img.load()
    
    w = img.size[0]
    h = img.size[1]

    print("Converting string to binary...")
    print(' '.join(format(ord(x), 'b') for x in string))
```

Please correct me if there's anything wrong with this! This is my first time using the `PIL` image library.

Comment: Did you try `image.save("namehere.png")`? See https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/handbook/tutorial.html

Comment: I don't know where to start with my code, let alone end. I know how to initialize (`Image.new(args)`), and that's working, I just need to know how you can change colors of pixels in a for loop (pixel by pixel)

Comment: It would help if you provide code you already have and explain how you generated the (very small) image

Comment: @ELinda I edited my post. I generated the image in photoshop.

Comment: You are putting more than two colors in the image so it's not a "binary" image — sounds like it's a "trinary" image.

Comment: There are a few issues with your question, maybe you could clarify. 1) You call your image *"binary"* but say it can be black, white or grey so it isn't binary, it's more greyscale. 2) Your code makes square images but your example is 3x9 which isn't square. 3) It's unclear what we are supposed to fill your image with as your example is incomplete. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkSetchell: The OP didn't make the image with the code in their question — they did it with some "photoshopping app".

Comment: The application turns a string into a binary string, like this: `"Hi!"` = `"1001000 1101001 100001"`. That is done with `' '.join(format(ord(x), 'b') for x in string)`. It then turns every "1" into a white pixel, every "0" into a black pixel and every " " into a light gray pixel.

Comment: @martineau Yes, thank you, I saw that. I was trying to establish if the 3x9 is what is wanted or the square. It's unclear to me what shape image is required if the function receives a 24 character string... 6x4? 4x6? 12x2? 8x3?

Comment: @MarkSetchell The ratio of the image depends on the length of the string, thats why I added `(round(len(string)), round(len(string)))` while initializing the Image object.

Comment: @zenof: How is `"Hi!"` = `"1001000 1101001 100001"` a binary string (which make no sense)?  Also an image with the dimension of `(round(len(string)), round(len(string)))` is a square. There's aren't enough characters in the string to fill it out (at least as far as you have explained so far).

Comment: @martineau A string with binary numbers in it I mean. Also yes it is a square, but just like in the picture I fill in the rest of the picture with a darker shade of gray that gets ignored by the application.

Comment: So if you pass in "Hi!" that's 3 characters, which at 8 pixels per character and with 2 grey pixels between, will make 26 pixels. Correct? But the image will be 3x3 which I make 9. So how do we fit 26 pixels in a 9 pixel image please?

Comment: I'm starting to see what you mean. The "H" makes "1001000" which is white, black, black, white, black, black, black, black which is what you see if you go **down** the lefmost column of your image starting at the top...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my best *guess* of how to do what you want. For a 3 character string it generates a 3x8 gray-scale `.png` format image, but the pixels in it are all either black (0) or white (255) since I never understood what you meant about where the light-gray pixels came from…

```
from PIL import Image

def makePicture(string, filename):
    w, h = len(string), 8
    img = Image.new("L", (w, h), 0x7f)  # Gray-scale image.

    # Convert string to pixels.
    pixels = []
    for value in (ord(ch) for ch in string):
        col = []
        mask = 0b10000000  # Bit mask.
        while mask:
            col.append(bool(value & mask) * 255)
            mask >>= 1  # Shift right one bit position.
        pixels.append(col)

    # Transfer pixels to image.
    for x in range(w):
        for y in range(h):
            img.putpixel((x, y), pixels[x][y])

#    img.show()
    img.save(filename)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    makePicture('Hi!', 'binary_image.png')
```

Here's an enlargement of the image it created from the sample string `'Hi!'`:

[image: enlarged version of image created]

Comment: Cool. I think there's a grey pixel after every 8 bits, i.e. after each character. And also any trailing, unfilled pixels at the end just to pad to fill the output square or rectangle or whatever shape it is supposed to be.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Yes, exactly. A space after every bit, and if there's space over in the picture, fill it with gray.